# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-google-recaptcha

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I am trying to use ng2-google-recaptcha component from https://github.com/leewinder/ng2-google-recaptcha. I did everything like it says on the page, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-google-recaptcha  
...
Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-google-recaptcha as "ng2-google-recaptcha" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

I googled, but couldn't come to solution. Please advise what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
mismas

Answer (score 1):

I didn't add things in systemjs.config.js file as it says in installation instructions.